# JavaScript click has different behavior than manual one

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

With prototype I'm listening for a click event on several checkboxes. On checkbox click I want to disable all `<select>` elements. I'm using prototype. So, I have this code:

```
$$('.silhouette-items input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('observe', 'click', function(event) {
            var liItem = this.up('li.item');      
            if(this.checked) {
                alert('checked');
                liItem.removeClassName('inactive');
                var selectItem = liItem.select('select');
                for(i=0;i<selectItem.length;i++) {
                    selectItem[i].disabled=false;   
                    if (selectItem[i].hasClassName('super-attribute-select')) {
                        selectItem[i].addClassName('required-entry');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert('unchecked');
                liItem.addClassName('inactive');
                var selectItem = liItem.select('select');
                for(i=0;i<selectItem.length;i++){
                    selectItem[i].disabled=true;
                    if (selectItem[i].hasClassName('super-attribute-select')) {
                        selectItem[i].removeClassName('required-entry');
                    }
                }
            }
            calculatePrice();
        });
```

When I manually click on the checkbox, everything seems to be fine. All elements are disabled as wanted.
However, I have also this button which on click event it fires one function which fires click event on that checkbox.

In Opera browser it works. In others, not. It's like Opera first (un)check and then executes event. Firefox first fires event, then (un)check element.

I don't know how to fix it.

The HTML:

```
<ul class="silhouette-items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="include-item-17" class="include-item"/>
    <select name="super_attribute[17][147]">(...)</select>
    <select name="super_group[17]">(...)</select>
    <button type="button" title="button" onclick="addToCart(this, 17)">Add to cart</button>
  </li>
  <!-- Repeat li few time with another id -->
</ul>
```

Another JS:

```
addToCart = function(button, productId) {
            inactivateItems(productId);
            productAddToCartForm.submit(button);
        }
inactivateItems = function(productId) {
             $$('.include-item').each(function(element) {
                var itemId = element.id.replace(/[a-z-]*/, '');
                if (itemId != productId && element.checked) {
                    simulateClickOnElement(element);
                }
                if (itemId == productId && !element.checked) {
                    simulateClickOnElement(element);
                }
            });
        }
simulateClickOnElement = function(linkElement) {
            fireEvent(linkElement, 'click');
        }
```

Where `fireEvent` is a Magento function that triggers an event

Comment: Can you use a `change` event instead of a `click`?

Comment: @clockworkgeek I was trying with that and it was not good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother simulating a onclick if you can get away with not doing so. Having a separate function that can be called from within the event handler *and* from outside should work in your case.

---

```
var handler = function(){
    //...
}
var nodeW = $('#node');
handler.call(nodeW);
```

Of course, this doesn't trigger all onclick handlers there might be but it is simpler so it should work all right. Points to note for when you use .call to call a function:

1. Whatever you pass as the first parameter is used as the `this` inside the call. I don't recall exactly what JQuery sets the `this` too but you should try passing the same thing for consistency.
2. The other parameters become the actual parameters of the function. In my example I don't pass any since we don't actually use the event object and also since I don't know how to emulate how JQuery creates that object as well.

Comment: I see your point here. Rethinking and reimplementing isn't bad idea here. Thanks, I'll consider it later.

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
fireEvent(linkElement, 'click');
```

with

```
linkElement.click();
```

works in firefox 5 and safari 5.1, so maybe the problem lies in the fireEvent() method.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know `click()` function may not working in older IE. Actually I was using it at first, but some people from my company said that they used `fireEvent` because it's more compatible across browsers.